How to download zip archive using Archiver and Next.js?
I'm using Next.js and want to create a route to download a zip archive created with Archiver.
The problem is: how to pass Archiver to NextResponse?
Here is my code:
const filesPath = "./data/files/";
const archive = Archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });
GetFilesFromKey(token).forEach((filename) => {
    archive.file(filesPath + token + "/" + filename.filename, { name: filename.filename });
});
archive.finalize();

// Here needs to be the code that converts "archive" to "BodyInit"

return new NextResponse(SOME BODY INIT, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="files.zip"`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    },
});


I fixed it:
const filesPath = "./data/files/";
const archive = Archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });
const readableStream = new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
        // Pipe data from the archive to the stream
        archive.on('data', (chunk) => {
            controller.enqueue(chunk);
        });

        // Handle errors
        archive.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error('Archiver error:', err);
            controller.error(err);
        });

        // Close the stream when the archive finishes
        archive.on('end', () => {
            controller.close();
        });

        // Add files to the archive
        GetFilesFromKey(token).forEach((filename) => {
            archive.file(filesPath + token + "/" + filename.filename, { name: filename.filename });
        });

        // Finalize the archive
        archive.finalize();
    },
});

return new NextResponse(readableStream, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="files.zip"`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    },
});

